# Prevent Nautilus to copy files with ":" to external NTFS USB-HDD

Tags: nautilus, ntfs

Ubuntu 20.04, ext4, 5.13.0-52-generic, Dual Boot with Win11.

Often I copy files with Nautilus to an external NTFS USB-HDD, unfortunately I overlook sometimes that the filename includes a ":". It leads to an error in the NTFS-FAT, checked by Win11. And a recovery of the file will all ways be necessary.

Is it possible to configure Nautilus or something else in the system, that characters like ":" in the filename

(or "?"..., please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721147/invalid-characters-in-a-filename-on-windows for the complete list),

will denied the copy operation.
Thank you for help.

Comment: I suggest 5 lines to program : if copy to NTFS, for string array check letters, if true exit.

Comment: It depends on the fstab entry for ext, NTFS HDDs. If present the copy operation is possible, if not the copy operation will be denied by the system. Please refer to : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418122/is-it-possible-with-an-fstab-entry-to-get-the-ntfs-wrong-copy-prevent-feature for more details of the fstab entry.