# Is it possible with an fstab entry to get the NTFS wrong copy prevent feature

Tags: fstab, ntfs

Ubuntu 20.04, 5.13.0-52-generic
fstab entry :

```
UUID=90DAAA5CDAAA3DFA    /media/richard/WD_8T_Ext      ntfs         defaults,nls=utf8,nofail  0       0
```

If I copy files like "filme:  _.txt" to the given external HDD, the system will do it, it leads to a wrong FAT entry, and it must be corrected with Windows.

If I remove the fstab entry, and I copy the file, e.g.: with Nautilus, I will get the message from the system : "Error copy operation ...", and nothing will be done, the correct behavior.
What is to do, to get the copy prevent feature, but with an fstab entry ?
Thank you for help.

Comment: I must confess, the better question would be "... to behave the NTFS wrong copy prevent  ..."

Comment: Please do it by yourself : Copy a file like filme:  _.txt with Nautilus to a ext.NTFS- HDD with and without the given fstab entry.

Comment: Copy a file like filme:  _.txt with Nautilus to a ext. NTFS- HDD with and without the given fstab entry. With the fstab entry you will get no error indication, without the entry, you will get the error information, no file will be copied : "the copy prevent feature", it is declared by me.

Comment: As clear as possible : With the fstab entry, I will get no error message by the system. This leads to a wrong entry of the FAT of the HDD. Without the fstab entry I will get the system information "error copy of file" (or something similar). And I ask for an fstab entry but to behave the feature, files with "wrong" file names will not be copied to NTFS.HDD.

Comment: Beneath, the fstab entry does work, I needed it for DLNA. But obviously it switch off, the  recognition of NTFS file naming convention.

Comment: Why not check the mount options that you get without using fstab by running `mount`?

Comment: Please in more detail what you mean.

Comment: do you mean  windows_names? Window_names prevents the use of invalid windows characters:
(which are the nine characters ” * / : < > ? \ | and those whose code is less than 0×20)  One suggestion of parameters for NTFS: `nofail,noatime,windows_names,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,async,big_writes`

Comment: Yes of course, I mean invalid windows characters, as like invalid linux characters : "/". I did compare the mount output with an fstab entry and without fstab entry. mount output with fstab entry : /dev/sdd2 on /media/richard/WD_3T_Ext type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2) and without fstab entry : /dev/sdb2 on /media/richard/WD_3T_Ext1 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2). But copy of files with invalid characters is possible

Comment: Please refer to comment above : "But copy of files with invalid characters is possible with fstab entry, without fstab entry it is not possible (as like if I rename a file on ext4 to ".../.txt", it will be denied). In both cases the mount options are identical.